# Angular code not running in Angular 11.2.12

Tags: angular

The below code is not running in Angular 11.2.12. where as it is working in angular 6.0.3

product.component.ts Component class

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-product',
     templateUrl: './product.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
   })

    export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

     products:Object[];
     constructor() {
     this.products = [
        {
          id:"1",
          name:"Mac Book Pro"
        },
        {
          id:"2",
          name:"Iphone"
        }

    ];
   }

     public getProducts(){
      return this.products;
     }
   ngOnInit():void {
   }

 }
```

product.component.html

```
    Product Details:
   <div *ngFor="let product of products">
    <h1>{{product.id}}</h1>
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
   </div>
```

When I am running this I am seeing error message below

Error: src/app/product/product.component.html:3:19 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

3

## {{product.id}}

~~

src/app/product/product.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.

Error: src/app/product/product.component.html:4:19 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'.

4

## {{product.name}}

~~~~

src/app/product/product.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.

I tried <div *ngFor="let product of getProducts()">

Comment: Can you try and add safe operator on the products? like so `{{product?.id}}` `{{product?.name}}` ?

Comment: You declared projects as type Object[] thus the compiler is looking for a 'name' or 'id' attribute on your products which it does not find. Try declaring it as `any[]` if you don't want to provide type information or use an interface that represents your products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change type of products from object to below:

```
products: {id: string, name: string}[];
```

That is because Angular introduced Template type checking from version 9.x which has 3 different modes basic, full and strict. You can find more information on the Angular website as well.

Comment: Thanks Devang. worked for me. Is there are any chnages from Agular 6.0.3 to 11.2.12 in declartion?